# How do I set up Visual Studio Code Intellisense for Tone.js?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, tone.js

I'm trying to learn how to use the Tone.js library, writing my code in Visual Studio Code. How can I set VSC up to use Intellisense with this library?

Comment: If you have done `npm install tone` in your project, there is no need to do anything extra, you just need to import the library and you will get intellisense for that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a real programming noob - I didn't realise I had to do the npm install in the project directory. You pointed me in the right direction, so if you want to post your comment as an answer I can give you some rep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have done npm install tone in your project, there is no need to do anything extra, you just need to import the library and you will get intellisense for that.

If you have any more questions, let me know!

Comment: I did have to move the .d.ts file as VSC couldn’t spot it.